# Check if field value updated on sql server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How I can check field value updated in this trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.OrderApprovedSms 
   ON  dbo.[Order]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /*How can check approve date is updated*/
    IF (/*ApproveDate is updated*/)
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO office.SmsSendBuffer
               ( Number ,
                 Body 
               )
       SELECT 'xxxxxx','ORDER APPROVED!'
    END

END
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what sort of check on `ApproveDate` you want to perform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple, you can use the UPDATE function for checking field value update.

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.OrderApprovedSms 
   ON  dbo.[Order]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /*How can check approve date is updated*/
    IF (UPDATE (ApproveDate))
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO office.SmsSendBuffer
               ( Number ,
                 Body 
               )
       SELECT 'xxxxxx','ORDER APPROVED!'
    END

END
```

Comment: Be aware. The Update() will be true if *ANY* of the rows was updated. It'll work in a case of a single row update, but you should always code you trigger to handle multiple rows.

Answer (score 4):

It would be something like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.OrderApprovedSms 
   ON  dbo.[Order]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO office.SmsSendBuffer
         ( Number ,
             Body 
         )
    SELECT 'xxxxxx','ORDER APPROVED!' --No columns from inserted or deleted?
    FROM inserted i INNER JOIN deleted d
        ON i.<primary key column 1> = d.<primary key column 1> AND
           i.<primary key column 2> = d.<primary key column 2> AND
           i.ApprovedDate != d.ApprovedDate --Not sure what actual check you wanted to perform
END
```

Where [`deleted` and `inserted`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) are pseudo-tables that contain the row(s) that the `UPDATE` statement has affected (corresponding to their state before and after the statement)

There's a function, called [`UPDATE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) which answers the question "was this column subject to an update during this `UPDATE` statement?" but it a) Only answers for the entire **set** of rows in `inserted` and `deleted` and b) doesn't let you distinguish updates that has no actual effects from those that did (e.g. if you do `SET Column=2` where `Column` is already `2`, it still answers that `Column` was updated)

---

As an example of how pointless I think the `UPDATE` function is, consider the following:

```
create table T (ID int not null,Col1 int not null)
go
create trigger TT on T after update
as
    IF UPDATE(Col1)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Hello',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
    END
go
update T set Col1 = Col1
```

Which prints `Hello` in the output - so, we have an `UPDATE` that affected `0` rows (because the table is new) and even if there were any rows, would not have changed any data.

Comment: To the join on inserted and deleted, I'd also add `OR (i.ApproveDate IS NOT NULL AND d.ApproveDate IS NULL) --Assigning value to ApproveDate that was previously NULL`

Comment: @DMason - probably. I'll wait to see if the OP elaborates a bit more on what sort of checks they want to perform.

Answer (score 1):

use the `inserted` table, it will contain the new row(s).  `deleted` will contain the old row(s).

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` can contain 0, 1 or **multiple** rows. Talking or thinking about "the" row tends to produce code that is broken in the face of multi-row inserts, updates or deletes, and also those changes that actually affected 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable(Col1, COl2, Col3)
SELECT t.Col1, t.COl2, t.Col3
FROM TableName t
WHERE EXISTS
         (
          SELECT 1
          FROM inserted i INNER JOIN deleted d 
          ON i.PK_Col = d.PK_Col
          WHERE i.Date_Col <> d.Date_Col
          AND d.PK_Col = t.PK_Col
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:- Posting this as a separate comment, as I don't have enough points to add comments.

You have two options for this, UPDATE() and COLUMNS_UPDATED() . Posting a sample script which uses UPDATE() function, External links are provided for UPDATE() and COLUMNS_UPDATED(). Please have a look on those links for a detailed description.

```
use TempDb 
Go 
create table test ( n1 int , n2 int , n3 int ) 
go 
create table testCopy ( n1 int , n2 int , n3 int ) 
go 
create trigger TestTrg
on  test
after update 
as 
if update(n3)  -- This is the key function
               -- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx -- COLUMNS_UPDATED() 
               -- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx -- UPDATE() 
   insert into testCopy (n3 )  select n3 from deleted
go 
insert into test values ( 1, 2, 3 ) ,( 2, 3, 4) 
go 

update test set n2 = n2 + 1  -- no values would be inserted into testcopy
update test set n1 = n1 + 1  -- no values would be inserted into testcopy

update test set n3 = n3 +1 where n3 = 3  -- one row will be inserted into test copt
```